# 「どちらにしても」の意味は何ですか

Tags: grammar

「どちらにしても」はどう使うのですか？
読解テキストに出てきましたが、使い方がまだ分かりません。

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://www.eigo-gate.com/blog/phrase-kijhon/either-way/

Answer (score 2):

It means "no matter which one (you) choose". First of all, にする means *to choose*. For example, you could say:

> コーヒーにする

And it would mean *I choose coffee* (instead of tea, for example).

どちら means which one, so どちらにする would be a question meaning *which one do you choose?*

Now when we have interrogative pronouns like 何, 誰 or どちら, there are some words you can add after them to change what they mean. In this case, we'd have でも, which means *no matter*. If 何 is *what*, 何でも is *no matter what*, or *whatever*. If 誰 is *who*, 誰でも means *no matter who*, or *whoever*. And if どちら is *which one*, どちらでも is *no matter which one*.

The thing is that there words you add after interrogative pronouns don't always immediately follow the pronoun itself. If you said どちらでもにする, you would mean *I choose no matter which one*. That's correct, but if you want to say *no matter what you choose*, that でも (which means *no matter what*) must be after the verb. Whenever we have で in japanese attached to nouns or pronouns, the same structure is formed with the て form of a verb. In this case, the verb is する, so we change it to て form, して, and then add も.